# strategy entry and exit using heikin ashi but it shows error in longcondition

Tags: pine-script

It shows error in long condition. I have added the error also

Error:

```
Add to Chart operation failed, reason: line 16: Syntax error at input 'openHA'
```

is there any way to rectify this error

I have added code below-

```
//@version=4 

strategy("Heikin Ashi Strategy on normal candles", shorttitle="HA Strategy", overlay=true)

openHA  = security(heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), timeframe.period, open)
closeHA = security(heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), timeframe.period, close)
highHA  = security(heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), timeframe.period, high)
lowHA  = security(heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), timeframe.period, low)

fromYear = year > 2019
toYear = year < 2021

longCondition = openHA = lowHA and closeHA[2] > openHA[2] 
if (longCondition and fromYear and toYear)
strategy.entry("Long 1", strategy.long)

closeCondition = closeHA = highHA
if (closeCondition)
strategy.close("Long 1")

plot(close)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you have two `=` variable assignments in the statement. For the "equals to" logical operation you use two : `openHa == lowHA`. The same error on the `closeCondition` line and you need to indent/nest operations within the if statements.

```
if (longCondition and fromYear and toYear)
    strategy.entry("Long 1", strategy.long) // <-- this line one tab indented
```

Comment: Instead of = i used <= which works. Thanks